# Initializing objects on PHP MVC - before view or during

Tags: php, oop, object, model-view-controller, view

I'm building a simple MVC Framework and stuck in how i set up the objects.

**TL;DR**: Is better initialize objects before the view or during the view render?

Example:

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
class Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $user = new User();
    }
}
?>
```

**OBJECT USER**

```
<?php
class User {
    public function __construct() {
       $this->setFriends($arg);
    }
    public function setFriends($arg) {}
    public function getFriends() {}
}
?>
```

**OBJECT FRIEND**

```
<?php
class Friend {
    .. properties ..
    .. methods() ..
}
?>
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php
foreach($user->getFriends() as $friend){
    .. $friend is a Friend Object already ..
    .. html...
}
?>
```

*The question*: Is better initialize Friend object on setFriends method (before the load view - remember, there are a lot of friends) or on getFriends method (on load view)?

```
public function setFriends($arg) {
    foreach($arg as $item)
        $this->friends[] = new Friend($item)
}
```

**OR**

```
public function getFriends() {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($this->friends as &friend)
        $tmp[] = new Friend($friend)
    return $tmp;
}
```

I think in the first case, memory will be pre consumed. And the second case, the Friend Object will initialize only if the view call getFriends.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an either/or situation. If you are given new data, then you need to call setFriends which assigns the new objects. What is `$this->friends` and why do you create a temporary array of Friend objects to return? We need more information about the code's usage. What is the expected use case of calling the get/set? How many times are they called? etc. In OOP typically the objects are created once you have the data to initialize them.

Comment: The general propose of this implementation is to pass to view (in the foreach) the object initialized (i want to uncouple the view from the model/controller/new objects functions, think like another person building the view.. he don't need to initialize the friend object (is already passed)...  I do not know if I was clear (sorry my english)

Comment: Then the View is not a good place for either of your get/set functions. These belong in the Controller, thus separating the View from the creation of the Friend objects all together. Note, getFriends should return `$this->friends` and avoid the copying all together. It will still be a copy unless you change the function to `&getFriends()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb:

Anything that's required to make every page load should be required universally early on in the initialization (usually in a boostrap layer or similar). This includes things like a base controller (from which others extend), base view (same deal here), database handler object, etc.

Anything that's specific to just one page, as you seem to be describing with users and friends, should be loaded in the controller or controller action which handles loading that page. This helps keep your code focused and your memory footprint down.

In these cases it is always better to move as much of the business logic out of your views as you can, and save your PHP in views for simple things like loops and echos. In MVC frameworks you'll often see arrays built in a controller, so that lots of data that has already been finalized can be passed to the view. For example, within your controller you could instantiate your user to pass to the view as an argument, and then also instantiate your friends and add them all to an array of friends that you pass as another argument. Or combine these two arrays into one big array, and pass a single 'parameters' argument to the view. This would then be a standard parameter that all your views could share, and then picking apart the array of data happens within the view itself.

Other options become more viable depending on what information you need to be available about friends. For instance, when instantiating a user you could also (within the constructor) instantiate each one of their friends, assign to an array, and save them all as a property of that user. This does make a bulkier object, and you have to consider if you're using a lot of users how much this will cost.

You could, however, only need friends in certain circumstances so it may make more sense to instantiate them when you need them, instead of always having them even when you don't. If this is the case, your user should at least have a lookup of its friends, and be able to set a property within itself that will hold the info you need to look up a friend. This means that whether it's included in your user constructor (if you'll always need to know what friends a user has), or in a separate function like getFriends (if you only sometimes have to know about a user's friends), you'll need to have at least an ID of each friend that can be stored as a property of your user, so you can later loop through it and instantiate friends based on id.

Overall I think the important point is regarding context. Where you create an object directly affects two main things: where it is accessible, and how much memory you waste. You always need to weigh those two and strike the balance. My best advice is to restrict where data exists and where it is accessible as much as possible, to only those places where it has to be. This will keep you application the most secure and use the least memeory.

I know it's a lot to think about, but I hope this helpled!

Comment: Thanks! help me a lot!!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.